# Send Message Directly to Discord Client Inside Function

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get my code to check if two strings are equal inside a list.  If they are not equal, then a message should be sent directly to the discord client.  If they are, it should just move on with the function.  I'm getting an error that says "NoneType" object has no attribute send.  If I copy the lines:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)
    await channel.send("Message")
```

and just remove the `await` and paste it outside the function, I dont get an error.  I'm assuming theres something wrong with my global declarations, but I'm not sure.  Can someone help?

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

# instantiating discord client
token = "redacted"
client = discord.Client()


@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def scrape():
    global linksAndTitles
    global pbe_titles
    global currPatch
    global allTitles
    global recentPatches
    global currTemp
    temp = []

    URL = "redacted"
    page = urlopen(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    pbe_titles = soup.find_all('redacted', attrs={'redacted': 'redacted'})
    for tags in pbe_titles:
        temp.append(tags.text.strip())
    tempCurr = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in temp[:1])
    if tempCurr != currTemp:
        channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)
        await channel.send("Message")
```

It's those last two lines that throw the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

What the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` means is that your `channel` variable is not getting any channel from `bot.get_channel(123456789)`, which is why the value of `channel` becomes `None`. I don't see anything wrong code-wise, so the problem must be with the channel id that you're passing in. Make sure to correctly copy the id of the channel you want and then paste it into the `channel = bot.get_channel(id)` line.

Comment: It's not an issue with the channel id.  I've made sure that portion is correct.  It appears to be an issue directly with the `channel.send` as it's not recognizing what a channel is.  That's what I've gathered.

Comment: So my code works if, at the loop beginning : `if tempCurr == currTemp:` the operand is `==` but for some reason, breaks when `!=` is the operand

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be your mixing between `bot` and `client`, an example which shows this is, you have defined both at the beginning of your code, but both of them cannot work well as a pair. You should be sticking to one, and thats why it can't read the id, because bot is just `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` which does not connect to the `discord.client` your client is defined as `client = discord.Client()`

This is the line the issue would be occurring,

And if you look to the top of your code, you can see bot is only defined as `command_prefix='!'`

```
channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)
```

So instead by using one, in this case `client`, they should both defined like this,

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
```

That means the rest of your code should **only** be using `client`, here is it included in your code,

```py
token = "redacted"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')


@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def scrape():
    global linksAndTitles
    global pbe_titles
    global currPatch
    global allTitles
    global recentPatches
    global currTemp
    temp = []

    URL = "redacted"
    page = urlopen(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    pbe_titles = soup.find_all('redacted', attrs={'redacted': 'redacted'})
    for tags in pbe_titles:
        temp.append(tags.text.strip())
    tempCurr = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in temp[:1])
    if tempCurr != currTemp:
        channel = client.get_channel(123456789)
        await channel.send("Message")
```

However, if you still want to use `bot`, just remember to stick to it and the opposite shouldn't need to by in your code. Hope this works for you. Also make sure you are running the bot token properly and at the bottom of your code

Comment: So, my issue is actually with my loop for some reason: If I change my loop to be `if tempCurr == currTemp` there's no break.  The code continues and works correctly.  However, if I keep `if tempCurr != currTemp` the code breaks.